# Gmail open tracking pixel is status:blocked

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, email-studio, gmail

In every email you send from salesforce marketing cloud, you send an `open.aspx` (open tracking) request in the form of:

Request URL: `https://click.my.delegated_domain.com/open.aspx?HASH-KEY`

When i go to `Chrome > Developer Tools > Network`

The request is flagged as `status:blocked`.

If i copy the URL and open it in a new tab, i get status 200 OK. I have confirmed that a friend to whom i sent the email to as well has it working.

I made sure all cookies are allowed, the site permissions are all enabled and i updated chrome. This works in Firefox and Safari.

Has anyone had this issue or knows a fix? Thanks.

Comment: Did you do a test send to your gmail inbox, to verify whether or not the open event gets registered?

Comment: Try replacing the "?" with %3F in your link